# Retrieving IP addresses allocated over a wireless hosted network

Tags: windows, networking, c++-cli, ip-address, netsh

I want to perform what appears to me as a very simple task. I started a wireless hosted network on Win7 using `netsh wlan start hostednetwork...` and all was fine. Even the communication could be established with the remote device.

Using `arp -a -v` I can see the list of IP addresses and found the IP address of my remote device to be 192.168.173.xx.

Now, I just want to discover this address using C++/CLI (.NET 4.5). I never worked with networks but I'm not a beginner with .NET. However, I cannot find anything. All I tried failed to give me the answer. There should be a simple way, no?

The reason why I need that is because the remote device acts as the server so I need to send my requests from my PC to that device's address... That's all.

Someone knows how to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I found myself the solution to this question...

```
GetIpNetTable2()
```

Then scan the table this function returns. See [this link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

It uses Win32 functions rather than C++/CLI but it can be mixed.